# Remove W11 "System requirements not met" watermark?

Tags: windows-11

I have the  "System requirements not met" watermark on the lower right above the systray, how to remove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regedit navigate to:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER>UnsupportedHardwareNotificationCache

in the right pane set the SV2 dword to 0

if there is no SV2 Dword, create one.

Restart the PC and watermark should be gone.

If you prefer using gpedit Go to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System.

find "Hide messages when Windows system requirements are not met" and set to disabled.

[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb5017130-managing-windows-11-system-requirements-not-met-message-in-your-organization-f751d24b-a70c-4a18-9eec-dae0790e41f5)